# SQL - Counting Records and Pulling Min Dates

Tags: sql

I have two tables I am working from. One is for Contracts (CNT), and has all the relevant info on ID#, Administrators, Expiry Dates etc. The other is for Amendments (AMD), which has similar information, but is concerned only with amendments to the contracts, obviously. They appear something like this:

```
CNTRCT_ID | CNTRCT_ADMIN | CNTRCT_START_DT | .....
12345       J. Bloggs      01-01-2018        .....
54321       A. Nonymous    02-01-2018        .....
12121       B. Atman       03-01-2018        .....

REF_ID    | AMEND_ID     | AMEND_DT        | .....
12345       A00123         06-06-2018        .....
12345       A00265         09-09-2018        .....
54321       A02451         05-04-2018        .....
```

What I'm seeking to do is join the two tables (CNT.Contract_ID = AMD.Ref_Id being the keys) which is fine, but where I'm running into issues is the count and minimum date. When joined, you get an output where the contract info will duplicate (for Amd 1, 2, etc.) as each Amendment has a unique Amendment_ID (not the Ref_ID, which ties to contract id). So we get:

```
CNTRCT_ID | CNTRCT_ADMIN | CNTRCT_START_DT | REF_ID    | AMEND_ID     | AMEND_DT |
12345       J. Bloggs      01-01-2018        12345       A00123         06-06-2018
12345       J. Bloggs      01-01-2018        12345       A00265         09-09-2018
54321       A. Nonymous    02-01-2018        54321       A02451         05-04-2018
```

Where entries for Contract 12121 are dropped as no AMD.REF_ID = '12121' exists.

Basically, i want to pull Contract Information then tie this to Amendment info, if applicable but a) counting the number of amendments per contract (note: just taking the maximum Amendment number here won't work as some have one or more 0th amendments which must be counted for this purpose).  What I'm trying to work towards is an output of the style:

```
CNTRCT_ID | AMD_COUNT | FIRST_AMD_DT
12345       2           06-06-2018
54321       1           05-04-2018
12121       0           N/A
```

I can write

```
COUNT(*) over (partition by CNT.CNTRCT_ID) AS AMD_COUNT
```

and this will tally up all the contract entries and output the count in a new column, and I can combine this with DISTINCT(CNT.CNTRCT_ID) in the Select clause, which removes duplicates but I also need that earliest Amendment date in there and I'm having a hard time getting it in there without throwing something off. If I Use

```
select min(AMEND_DT) from dbo.AMENDMENTS AMD1 where AMD1.REF_ID = AMD.REF_ID
```

I seem to lose amendments in the count. One contract I know for a fact has 11 amendments outputs 11 if I removed the the Min Date field and clause, but only 2 with it. Any help getting to the kind of output above with accurate results is what I'm looking for.

This is the skeleton of what I have. I'm sure there is something obvious I'm missing, but any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT   DISTINCT(CNT.CNTRCT_ID), CNT.CNTRCT_TYP_CD (& various CNT fields), AMD.AMEND_DT,
         COUNT(*) over (partition by CNT.CNTRCT_ID) AS AMD_COUNT
FROM     dbo.AMENDMENTS AMD, 
         dbo.CONTRACTS CNT 
WHERE    CNT.CNTRCT_ID=AMD.REF_ID 
AND      AMD.AMEND_DT = (select min(AMEND_DT) from dbo.AMENDMENTS AMD1 where AMD1.REF_ID=AMD.REF_ID)
```

Comment: **must know** which database you are using. "sql" as a tag is not sufficient by itself, please add tag(s)  to tell us which variant of sql is needed.

Comment: By the way. `distinct` is NOT a function so the parentheses you have used after distinct are simply ignored.  `select distinct`  is a row operator, it tests if the whole row is distinct from all other rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have already used a window function, may I suggest you do the same for the minimum date:

```
SELECT /* DISTINCT */
    CNT.CNTRCT_ID
  , CNT.CNTRCT_TYP_CD
  , COUNT( * ) OVER (PARTITION BY CNT.CNTRCT_ID)      AS AMD_COUNT
  , AMD.AMEND_DT
  , MIN( AMEND_DT ) OVER (PARTITION BY CNT.CNTRCT_ID) AS AMD_DT_MIN
FROM dbo.AMENDMENTS AMD
INNER JOIN dbo.CONTRACTS CNT ON CNT.CNTRCT_ID = AMD.REF_ID
```

I don't really know if you need `select distinct` but do note the word distinct is a qualifier of select, i.e. there are 2 options for select: `select all` or `select distinct` but `all` is the default and is usually just omitted.

I recommend you use "explicit joins". Over 25 years ago ANSI standards formalized that syntax.

To remove `distinct` group the amendment data before joining:

```
SELECT
    CNTRCT_ID
  , COALESCE( AMD_COUNT, 0 ) AS AMD_COUNT
  , AMD_DT_MIN
FROM CONTRACTS
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            REF_ID
          , MIN( AMEND_DT ) AS AMD_DT_MIN
          , COUNT( * )      AS AMD_COUNT
        FROM AMENDMENTS
        GROUP BY
            REF_ID
    ) G ON CONTRACTS.CNTRCT_ID = G.REF_ID
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew I'd want to pull distinct rows based on the contract info so that was in there from the start. Adding in the AMD date info (a late management suggestion) kinda threw it off. The contract info doesn't change for any of the duplicate entries, only the information from the amendment tables change. I'm sure this is why it 'works' and gives me the tallies I want when the date isn't required, but when the date is added it's causing the problem since that's coming from the AMD table.

Comment: @Used_By_Already, your solution wouldn't return all rows from Contracts table in case there were some with no corresponding rows in Amendments. Am I right?

Comment: All contracts would be returned, that's what the `left join` does.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the previous version of your answer.

Comment: Just threw this into AQT and initial results are looking positive! Will need a little bit of tweaking to get it just so, but this is a huge leap forward. Thanks. I upvoted the solution, but it won't show since I'm so new here.

Comment: Cheers for the heads up. Have now done so. My tweaks are complete, I managed to not break anything, and the query is running like a charm. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works for you:

```
 WITH CTE AS (SELECT MIN(AMEND_DT) AS FIRST_AMD_DT,  COUNT(*) AS AMD_COUNT, REF_ID FROM AMENDMENTS GROUP BY REF_ID)
 SELECT CNTRCT_ID, COALESCE(AMD_COUNT,0) AS AMD_COUNT, FIRST_AMD_DT AS  FIRST_AMD_DT FROM CONTRACTS LEFT JOIN CTE ON CNTRCT_ID = REF_ID
```

Hope it helps.